# Nonstandard structure of Presburger arithmetic

Tags: model-theory, nonstandard-analysis, presburger-arithmetic

Let $\mathfrak {R}_A = (\Bbb {N}; 0, S,<,+)$. What can we say about ${}^{\ast}\Bbb N$, the universe of non-standard structure of the first order theory of $\mathfrak {R}_A$?

Firstly, because of the property every non-zero element must have a predessor and a successor, ${}^{\ast}\Bbb N$ must be a union of $\Bbb N$ and multiple $\Bbb Z$-chain which is ${}^{\ast}\Bbb N = \Bbb{N} \cup (A \times \Bbb {Z})$. So the problem reduces to what should the set $A$ be like.

Secondly since for every element either  itself or its successor must be some  element's double, $A$ must dense ordered set without a supremum and a infimum.

But there's still a lot of candidates for $A$, say $\Bbb R$, $(0,1)$, $\Bbb Q$. Can we sharpen this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is known is that if the model is countable, then $A=\mathbb Q$.  Since the ultrapower construction does not produce a countable model, $^\star \mathbb N$ must be more complicated.  It is probably hellishly complicated.

A good reference for this is Bovykin, Andrey; Kaye, Richard Order-types of models of Peano arithmetic. Logic and algebra, 275–285, Contemp. Math., 302, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2002.  A review may be found at http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1928396

Comment: Can we know that whether there's a countable model? It seems to me, because of the lack of multiplication, we may not need this model to be that complicated as indicated by ultrapower construction.

Comment: Who said anything about ultrapowers???

Comment: The OP asked a question about $^\star\mathbb N$.  These are the hypernatural numbers.  The easiest construction thereof is by means of an utrapower of $\mathbb N$, as the OP and I have discussed in a number of earlier questions.  So I am not sure I understand your question.  Possibly I misunderstood the OP's original question; perhaps he could clarify.

Comment: I should appologize I misunderstood your answer at the begginning. If I understand your answer correctly this time, you mean that $\Bbb Q$ works, but $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ doesn't.